# Show that $\mathbb{P}(X>u)\leq\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u})$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$ where $g(x)$ is nonnegative and weakly increasing.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, random-variables, expected-value

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous random variable with density $f$. Let $g$ be a non-negative non-decreasing function with $\mathbb{E}(g(X))=1$. Show that $$\mathbb{P}(X>u)\leq \mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u}),\ \ \forall u\in\mathbb{R}.$$

---

I have the following attempt: since $\mathbb{E}g(X)=1$, we have that $$1=\int_{-\infty}^{u}g(x)f(x)dx+\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u})\leq g(u)\int_{-\infty}^{u}f(x)dx+\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u})=g(u)\mathbb{P}(X\leq u)+\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u}).$$ Write $\mathbb{P}(X\leq u)=1-\mathbb{P}(X>u)$, we have that $$g(u)\mathbb{P}(X>u)\leq g(u)-1+\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u}),$$ and thus $$\mathbb{P}(X>u)\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{g(u)}+\dfrac{\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u})}{g(u)}\leq 1+\dfrac{\mathbb{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{X>u})}{g(u)}.$$ I do not know how to push it further.

Another attempt is to use Markov inequality. Since $X$ is absolutely continuous and $g$ is non-decreasing and nonnegative, we have $$\mathbb{P}(X>u)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq u)=\mathbb{P}(g(X)\geq g(u))\leq\dfrac{\mathbb{E}g(X)}{g(u)}=\dfrac{1}{g(u)}.$$

What have I missed?

Comment: What is weakly increasing? Do you mean non-decreasing?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes. Non-decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g(u) \geq 1$, we have that, since $g(u) \leq g(X)$ on $\{X > u\}$,
$$
\Pr(X > u)
= \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X > u\}})
\leq \mathbf{E}(g(u)\mathbf{1}_{\{X > u\}})
\leq \mathbf{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X > u\}}).
$$

On the other hand, if $g(u) < 1$, we have analogously that
$$
\Pr(X \leq u)
= \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq u\}})
\geq \mathbf{E}(g(u)\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq u\}})
\geq \mathbf{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq u\}}),
$$
so that, since $\mathbf{E} g(X) = 1$,
$$
\Pr(X > u)
= 1 - \Pr(X \leq u)
\leq \mathbf{E}g(X) - \mathbf{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X \leq u\}})
= \mathbf{E}(g(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X > u\}}).
$$

Comment: Nice Proof. Thank you!